# Rules for nominalizing a verb

Tags: verbs, nouns, morphology, nominalizations

To nominalize a verb, you sometimes use the gerund.

> to happen --> a happening

Sometimes it's a different word.

> to arrive --> an arrival

so we don't write

> to arrive --> an *arriving

Is there a rule for when to use each method? Currently I just use whichever sounds good, being a native speaker.

Comment: That's because *arrival* comes from the French *arrivaille*

Comment: @nico: "to present" derives from Latin via French, but the noun is "presentation". I think you'd be hard put to define a rule based on whether the word "comes from French").

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I am not putting any rules. I am just saying that the specific case of *arrival* is because it derives from a French word. As for most of these things there is no rule, you use *arrival* and not *arriving* because you do. PS: *presentation* is a valid French word ;)

Comment: The overarching rule is "Use whichever sounds good, being a native speaker" :)

Comment: @nico: The first thing I learnt in French was "all English words ending in 'tion' are the same in French". Not 100% true, but it certainly works better than "I before e except after c".

Comment: @Neil -- that's *not* a rule.  It's almost a taunt.

Comment: You could, however, use "arriving" as a noun and as the subject of a sentence:  "Arriving early is not something we recommend."  Or, "His arriving early put us all into a dither."  On the other hand, with a twist as an adverb you could have, "Arriving early, he took a front-row seat confidently."  (I.e., "He took--arriving early--a front-row seat confidently."  Subject, verb, adverb, object, adverb.)

Answer (score 12):

The general rule for creating [gerunds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund#Gerunds_in_English) is:

> In English, the gerund is identical in form to the present participle (ending in -ing) and can behave as a verb within a clause (so that it may be modified by an adverb or have an object), but the clause as a whole (sometimes consisting of only one word, the gerund itself) acts as a noun within the larger sentence. For example: Eating this cake is easy.

The present participle of *to arrive* is *arriving*. This is its gerund form. While the noun form of *to happen* and its gerund are identical, *they are not the same thing.* They share a form, but the derivation of the gerund is not the derivation of a noun as well. There is a description of the differences here:

> Not all nouns that are identical in form to the present participle are gerunds.[3] The formal distinction is that a gerund is a verbal noun – a noun derived from a verb that retains verb characteristics, that functions simultaneously as a noun and a verb, while other nouns in the form of the present participle (ending in -ing) are deverbal nouns, which function as common nouns, not as verbs at all.

OK, so when do you use *"-ing"* to create a noun? The [dictionary entry on the suffix -ing](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/-ing) says that -ing is:

> **a suffix of nouns formed from verbs, expressing the action of the verb or its result, product, material, etc.** ( the art of building; a new building; cotton wadding ).  It is also used to form nouns from words other than verbs ( offing; shirting ).  Verbal nouns ending in -ing  are often used attributively ( the printing trade )  and in forming compounds ( drinking song ).  In some compounds ( sewing machine ),  the first element might reasonably by regarded as the participial adjective, -ing 2 ,  the compound thus meaning “a machine that sews,” but it is commonly taken as a verbal noun, the compound being explained as “a machine for sewing.”

Now, how do you know how to create a noun from a verb in general?

There is no set rule. As you can see from this [list of suffixes](http://www.xtec.es/%7Eogodoy/sac/wordbuilding/suffixes.htm), there are many endings that can get tacked onto a word. There are patterns (for example, you add "er" to a verb of activity, like "write" to "writer"), but no hard and fast rule. For reference, the list of noun suffixes which are added onto verbs or adjectives is:

> **Noun Suffixes**
>
> - er added to a verb is used for the person who does an activity: writer, worker, singer,... (sometimes -or, as in actor, sailor, supervisor,...)
> - er/-or are also used for things which do a particular job: tin-opener, projector, ...
> - er and -ee can contrast with each other, meaning "person who does something" (-er) and "person who receives or experiences the action" (-ee): employer/employee, ...
> - (t)ion is used to make nouns from verbs: communication, pollution, admission, ...
> - ist (person) and -ism (activity or ideology): marxist/Marxism, terrorist/terrorism, ...
> - ist is also used for people who play musical instruments: pianist, violinist, ...
> - al is added to some verbs to make nouns: arrival, refusal, ...
> - ness is used to make abstract nouns from adjectives: happiness, goodness, weakness, ...
> - ment is used to make abstract nouns from verbs: excitement, enjoyment, ...
> - hood is used to make abstract nouns, especially family terms, from nouns: childhood, brotherhood, ...
> - ship is used to make abstract nouns, especially status, from nouns: friendship, membership, partnership, ...
> - (i)ty is used to make abstract nouns from adjectives: honesty, loyalty, ...

Comment: ah nice, i wanted to ask the more general question too (how to noun a verb), seems like you covered it here. guess being a native speaker is the way to do it then, heh..

Comment: If you're a native speaker, go with your gut. You'll probably have an ear for what's right, rather than going by rules (which never seem to work)

Comment: I don't see why wouldn't that apply to a non-native person. In other words why a non-native would have to follow rules in a territory where there are thin boundaries.

Comment: @Bogdan If you're a NNS, you need to develop your gut. I'm not saying that other people need to follow rules, but they help teach a language which unfortunately somewhat irregular.

Comment: @simchona perhaps I had developed my gut already

Comment: @Bogdan Perhaps. I was just saying the native speakers tend to have developed this gut because they started with the language earlier and may have had more exposure. I do not mean to imply that NNSs don't have the gut.

Comment: Also -tion, a suffix for verbs derived from Latin, which forms a noun that can often be substituted for the gerund in a sentence, or which can be used as an abstract noun.

Answer (score 1):

This example helped me to understand that:

> I am watering the plant. [*watering* = verb]
>
> The plant needs watering. [*needs* = verb and *watering* = noun/gerund]