# Is it Decryptor or Decrypter?

Tags: grammar, orthography

I'm coding a decryption service and wondering which is the best name, `Decryptor` or `Decrypter` I had a quick look online and it appears -er and -or convert a verb to an agent noun, however is one preferable over the other?

Interestingly my Mac tells me to use the latter.

Comment: In some contexts, the -or is used for the person and the -er is used for the thing/device the person uses.  A weldor uses a welder for example.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. What you name something is up to you, but you may want to see *[What’s the rule for adding “-er” vs. “-or” when forming an agent noun from a verb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4733)*. Other questions of interest include *[Rules for nominalizing a verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37241)*, *[Difference between “commenter” and “commentator”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2350)*, *[What's the difference between “adviser” and “advisor” — are both interchangeable?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2714)*, and others.

Comment: @Jim No. In particular, *weldor* doesn't exist in OED, so its usage is vanishingly small.

Comment: @AndrewLeach This is an industry distinction that appears to have originated in mid-20th century U.S. manufacturing, and I wouldn't be surprised if it were an OED blind spot. *Welder* is standard for both the person and the machine, but a number of reliable sources in Google Books define it differently: ["A welder is a machine operated by the weldor"](https://books.google.com/books?id=aNHVAAAAMAAJ) (1953), ["Welder refers to the welding equipment. Weldor refers to the person using the welder"](https://books.google.com/books?id=qCmoaBtYjYkC&pg=PA56) (1982), and so on.

Comment: It is the case that OED's *welder* hasn't been looked at since 1926, but it's still a very dubious practice to refer someone to jargon -- which by definition is non-standard.

Comment: An article in *[Machinery](https://books.google.com/books?id=dAdGAQAAIAAJ)* Vol. 46 (1939) is enticingly titled *"Weldor" is Proposed as Name for Men Who Weld*, but I don't have access to it. From my skim of Wikipedia, technique and tools took a big leap forward in the 1920s, and welding as a trade became more distinct and specialized. A [thread](https://www.practicalmachinist.com/vb/fabrication-cnc-laser-waterjet-plasma-welding-and-fab/term-weldor-obsolete-151809) at PracticalMachinist.com asks "is the term 'Weldor' obsolete?" however, so perhaps *weldor*, like weldors, have had their day.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the comments, especially the references from @choster I think it's fair to say neither are *wrong* per se; however `Decrypter` seems to be the slightly better option because it's the more common form (especially in Great Britain), and in my case it's a tool rather than a person doing the decrypting.

Answer (score 1):

Both seem to be in use (looking at documentation for various tools online). According to [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=decryptor%2Cdecrypter&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdecryptor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdecrypter%3B%2Cc0) "-or" is very slightly more popular. Although only "-er" occurs in the British English sources. I'm not sure how much Google Ngrams can be trusted for the, though.

I would choose one and stick with it consistently.